# Android Media Player set Data Source FD failed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

My code was working just fine until I increased the number of songs.
I had 200 songs but when I put 200+ I noticed that I was receiving IOException setDataSource FD failed.

Now after some additional tests I found that the limit before this error is 334 songs which is strange. I don't understand why it plays ok with <334 and after 334 songs it crashes.

Could you please help me?
My code is very simple, here is the part.

```
ArrayList<MediaPlayer> mPlayerList = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
FileDescriptor fd = null;
    try {

  for (String fileName : fileList)
    {

            MediaPlayer mPlayerT = new MediaPlayer();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            fd = fis.getFD();
            //mPlayerT.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri1);
            mPlayerT.setDataSource(fd);
            mPlayerT.prepare();
            mPlayerT.setVolume(1f, 1f);
            mPlayerT.setLooping(false);
            mPlayerList.add(mPlayerT);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<mPlayerList.size()-1; i++) //Do not include last element
    {
        mPlayerList.get(i).setNextMediaPlayer(mPlayerList.get(i+1));
    }
mPlayerList.get(0).start();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Just to predict your answers, the files are not either incomplete from download or corrupted. I also converted them to .ogg from .mp3 just to be sure that everything is fine. When I receive the data source failed concerning a file, if I decrease the number of songs it is working correct without removing the specific file. So, the format of the files is ok.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, for one preparing over 300 songs before they're ready to be used probably isn't the best approach.  Also, it doesn't look like you're releasing the resources either unless that's somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @Submersed thanks for the answer. What do you suggest as best approach? To use 1 Media Player object and prepare/reset on completion event? I'm recreating the activity when the last song has played.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably running into memory issues would be my guess.  I'd use a managed pool of media players (incase you need to preload for previous, next, etc), but still only load them as needed -- not all at once.  Also, loading using prepareAsync is likely preferred to using prepare.  Lastly, make sure to close your input streams.

Comment: @Submersed ok will do. Thanks man. However, I'm a bit curious why I dont get a memory exception and I get a setdataSource failed...